# MySQL Join query from PHP script

Tags: php, mysql, join

I've created two tables, with these major fields:

1. registered_users (registration_id,first_name,last_name,login_id,password)
2. users_profile (profile_id,registration_id,first_name,last_name,relation_type,address,phone)

I've created a login.php file that runs the query on registered_users to check loginid and password and on successful login calls welcome.php file.

I have been able to execute a query (to check login) on registered_users table, however I need some help to write a query that will help me retrieve those profiles from users_profile table that matches the registration_id of the logged-in user.

//login.php

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST["loginid"]))
{
    $logid=strtolower($_POST["loginid"]);
    $passwd=$_POST["password"];

    require_once 'connection.php';

    $q="select email,password,registeration_id from registered_users where email='$logid'";

    $result=mysqli_query($conn,$q);

        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

    if ($row["password"] == $passwd && $row["email"]==$logid)

    {
            session_start();

            $_SESSION["login"] = $logid;

            // I need to nest a query here to select ONLY those profiles that belong to logged-in user

            $regid=$_row["registeration_id"];



$q2="SELECT registered_users.Registeration_id,profile.Relation_type,profile.first_name,profile.last_name from registered_users,profile WHERE registered_users.Registeration_id=$regid"; 



            $result2=mysqli_query($conn,$q2);

            $row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2);

            $_SESSION["fnm"]= $row2["first_name"];
            $_SESSION["lnm"]= $row2["last_name"];
            $_SESSION["rtyp"]= $row2["relation_type"];

            header("Location: Welcome.php" );
    } 

    else 

    {
            echo "Wrong Username or Password!";
    }


?>
```

The code contains the sql join query that needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a join here...change this line

```
$q2="SELECT registered_users.Registeration_id,profile.Relation_type,profile.first_name,profile.last_name from registered_users,profile WHERE registered_users.Registeration_id=$regid";
```

to this:

```
$q2="SELECT profile.Relation_type, profile.first_name, profile.last_name
     FROM profile 
     WHERE profile.Registeration_id = $regid";
```

Here, Registeration_id is a [foreign key](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) that will retrieve the data you need.

Comment: Indeed it works without using join on the two tables. I've rather used this query to fetch the result: 

$q2="SELECT registeration_id, relation_type, first_name, last_name FROM profile WHERE registeration_id ='$regid'";